# Convert multiple rows into one with semicolon as separator in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert this:

```
ID NAME
-------
1 AB
1 CD
1 EF
2 PQ
2 RS
```

to this:

```
ID NAME
----------
1 AB
1 AB;CD
1 AB;CD;EF
2 PQ
2 PQ;RS
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle (PL/SQL)?

Comment: Hi, I'm using MS SQL SERVER

Comment: Why do you want to have delimited data in the first place? That is generally very frowned upon in your RDBMS. It *looks* like you're going to need a triangular `JOIN` here though, as you can't use windowing with `STRING_AGG`, which could easily get slow. Finally, what defines the order your data is in? It's in name order, or something else you haven't given us?

Answer (score 1):

Using self join and string aggregation

```
select t1.id, coalesce(string_agg(t2.name,';') + ';', '') + t1.name name
from tbl t1
left join tbl t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t1.name > t2.name
group by t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Serg, You are a genius!

Comment: Can you please tell me how we can order names by its lengths, small to big.

Comment: @Rushikesh, `string_agg` supports `WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY.. )`  option